# How to make videos autoplay with sound in chrome or PWA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, youtube-api

Chrome's updated it auto play policy which block user from autoplaying the video. I am having signage board where it is most important feature for my application. Is there any way I can autoplay the video? Please let us know if any solution or workaround is available. As per google document you can run video with sound in PWA app. I have tried that as will but unable to play the video. Thank you in advance. (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#new-behaviors)

I have also referred multiple stack overflow question but haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: I remember read here on Stack Overflow about sending in code a key-event - like, sending space key pressed on javascript - for start the video with sound - create a [mvce] using jsfiddle, codeopen or another online tool available to see what you have tried so far.